# Responsive Website, set body to device-width

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want the body of the page to be responsive so that it is easy for the user to read on a mobile site.  But when I use this line of code.  I get this mess.  Any suggestions?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using media queries for min and max-width on specific platforms to get exact results.
You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!-- Try in this way it may help You --->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
```